# Column length change on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I changed field length named 'State'  from `nvarchar(1)` to `nvarchar(10)`.
Works properly on Server side.

But on client side (I use Delphi7 and connect with Adoquery) there is a problem after insert a record.

Client send 'Active' text to server but on server side it seems at table only 'A' character, not 'Active'.

Could anyone help ?

Comment: If you have specified field definitions, then double click the component, select the column whose definition you changed in database and modify its `Size` property from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change the property Size of your published field State to 10.
If you are sending data per parameterized queries you will have to adapt the Size of the parameters.

Comment: Hi again 
Size property is already 10 on Adoquery field properties. but I have still same problem

Comment: parameter solution solved problem. Thanks bummi. I can not vote due to my reputation is low. :((